# A sequence tending to zero where each element cannot be bounded by an integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am teaching myself measure theory and I working through http://homepages.uconn.edu/~rib02005/real.html. In exercise 7.3, they ask:

> Give an example of a sequence of non-negative functions $f_n$ tending to $0$ pointwise such that $\int f_n→0$, but there is no integrable function $g$ such that $f_n ≤ g$ for all $n$.

I am a novice in pure mathematics, so I would like some help in determining whether or not I am on the right path.

First, I believe I must find a sequence of function for which the $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n = 0$ *and* $\int f = 0$ if I interpret the question correctly.

I am approaching this problem by exploiting the fact that $f_n \leq g$ must hold for *all* $n$. Therefore, I only need to find a single $f_n$ for which the inequality is violated, as long as the function and its integral are zero in the limit.

I initially thought of $f_n=|\frac1n|$, since this is a non-negative function that satisfies the constraints above. However, I am not completely convinced if my reasoning is sound, or that I have understood the question.

Can you help me improve, or correct, my answer?

Comment: @PhoemueX: No, the sequence doesn't solve the question. The question assumes that each $f_n$ is integrable, otherwise the condition $\int f_n \to 0$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @stephn28: Try $f_n(x) = |\frac1n|$ if $n \le |x| < n+1$, and $f_n(x) = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: @TonyK: If we consider the extended real line $[0,\infty]$ (as is customary in measure theory), then it is possible for a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $[0,\infty]$ to converge to $0$, even if $x_n=\infty$ for some $n$. But still we must have $x_n <\infty$ for all **sufficiently large** $n$, so that $f_n$ will have to be integrable for all sufficiently large $n$. But indeed I did not read the post careful enough. I assumed the OP wante to take $f_1\equiv 1$ and $f_n =1$ for $n\geq 2$. I deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your suggestion is that $\int f_n$ does not seem to be finite if integrating a positive constant along the whole real line.

You could try something like

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} n &\mbox{if } 0 \lt x \lt \frac1{n^2} \\
0 & \mbox{otherwise. } \end{cases}$$

Comment: This is very helpful, you are employing $x$ and $n$ in a way I did not think of (I was simply using $n$). Thanks!